# Reading CSV files w/ MultiIndex

Tags: csv, pandas

I have a CSV file which looks like this:

```
State,Ownership Sector,Coal,Gas,Diesel,Total Thermal,Nuclear,Hydro,RES,Grand Total
Delhi,State,135,1550.4,0,1685.4,0,0,0,1685.4
,Private,0,108,0,108,0,0,18.53,126.53
,Central,4355.41,207.61,0,4563.02,122.08,666.12,0,5351.22
,Sub-Total,4490.41,1866.01,0,6356.42,122.08,666.12,18.53,7163.15
Haryana,State,3160,25,3.92,3188.92,0,884.51,70.1,4143.53
,Private,1620,0,0,1620,0,0,53.1,1673.1
,Central,1174,535.29,0,1709.29,109.16,478.67,0,2297.12
,Sub-Total,5954,560.29,3.92,6518.21,109.16,1363.18,123.2,8113.75
```

The first two columns should be read as a *MultiIndex*, So the first index column for the first four rows should be *Delhi*, and so on.  However, when I read this using `read_csv`, I get something like the following:

```
In [33]: pd.read_csv("data/econ/electricity_2012-13.csv", index_col=[0,1], skipinitialspace=True).ix[:8]
Out[33]: 
                             Coal      Gas  Diesel  Total Thermal  Nuclear  \
State   Ownership Sector                                                     
Delhi   State              135.00  1550.40    0.00        1685.40     0.00   
NaN     Private              0.00   108.00    0.00         108.00     0.00   
        Central           4355.41   207.61    0.00        4563.02   122.08   
        Sub-Total         4490.41  1866.01    0.00        6356.42   122.08   
Haryana State             3160.00    25.00    3.92        3188.92     0.00   
NaN     Private           1620.00     0.00    0.00        1620.00     0.00   
        Central           1174.00   535.29    0.00        1709.29   109.16   
        Sub-Total         5954.00   560.29    3.92        6518.21   109.16   

                            Hydro     RES  Grand Total  
State   Ownership Sector                                
Delhi   State                0.00    0.00      1685.40  
NaN     Private              0.00   18.53       126.53  
        Central            666.12    0.00      5351.22  
        Sub-Total          666.12   18.53      7163.15  
Haryana State              884.51   70.10      4143.53  
NaN     Private              0.00   53.10      1673.10  
        Central            478.67    0.00      2297.12  
        Sub-Total         1363.18  123.20      8113.75
```

I don't understand where the *NaN* are coming from; they're messing up my *MultiIndex* structure.

Any help understanding and resolving this issue is greatly appreciated =)

Comment: they are coming from the blank cells

Comment: So this means that pandas acutally puts a NaN into all first column cells which are empty, but those aren't displayed, right?  The question is how to get rid of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the rid the NaNs in your index you have two choices:

1. Edit the source file (might not be feasible)
2. Fill them in using pandas

So for the second option, you do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data/econ/electricity_2012-13.csv", skipinitialspace=True) \
       .fillna(method='ffill').set_index(['State', 'Ownership Sector'])
```

`fillna` is the method that replaces `NaN` values in a DataFrame or Series. You can specify values, but in this case, we told it to the the "ffill" (forward) fill method.

Comment: good idea to first read, then fill, and then assign the index.  I was stuck with the Index full of NaNs not knowing how to deal with that. Thanks!